# Spring Boot Reactive Websoket - Block out flux until received all information from client

Tags: spring-boot, websocket, reactive-programming, spring-webflux

I'm playing with reactive websocket (on spring boot 2.1.0) but I have an issue in trying to block the out flux waiting for client information.

I know that blocking is not the correct way to handle the reactive flow but I need to receive some information from the client before proceed (ie: an auth key, an id), there is an acceptable way to manage this in a reactive manner?

For example: I want the client to send an authorization key and a subscription id (to subscribe only to a specific event) and I will send the out flux only when I have both informations or close the session if the informations are not valid

I've tried to manage the check inside the handle method

```
     webSocketSession.receive().subscribe(inMsg -> {

            if(!inMsg.getPayloadAsText().equals("test-key")) {
                log.info("AUTHORIZATION ERROR");
                webSocketSession.close();
            }
        });
```

But this way is not working and is not correct because is managing the session kill in an "async" way and anyway also when receiving a message with the wrong key the session still remain alive

Another way is to keep a "session" using an in memory storage to keep track of the information received and handle this at business logic level

I'm stuck in figuring a correct way to manage it in a reactive way

My starting point was this example: http://www.baeldung.com/spring-5-reactive-websockets

Thanks in advance

ADDITIONAL INFORMATIONS:

Using the example https://github.com/eugenp/tutorials/tree/master/spring-5-reactive/src/main/java/com/baeldung/reactive/websocket

I've created a basic spring boot application and I've added a configuration class for the websocket:

```
@Configuration 
class WebConfig {

    @Bean
    public HandlerMapping handlerMapping() {
        Map<String, WebSocketHandler> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("/event-emitter-test", new MyWebSocketHandler());

        SimpleUrlHandlerMapping mapping = new SimpleUrlHandlerMapping();
        mapping.setUrlMap(map);
        mapping.setOrder(-1); // before annotated controllers
        return mapping;
    }

    @Bean
    public WebSocketHandlerAdapter handlerAdapter() {
        return new WebSocketHandlerAdapter();
    }
}
```

The following is the main class that is containing the main websocket method (modified with my actual code):

```
@Component
public class MyWebSocketHandler  implements WebSocketHandler {

    @Autowired
    private WebSocketHandler webSocketHandler;

    @Bean
    public HandlerMapping webSocketHandlerMapping() {
        Map<String, WebSocketHandler> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("/event-emitter-test", webSocketHandler);

        SimpleUrlHandlerMapping handlerMapping = new SimpleUrlHandlerMapping();
        handlerMapping.setOrder(1);
        handlerMapping.setUrlMap(map);
        return handlerMapping;
    }

    @Override
    public Mono<Void> handle(WebSocketSession webSocketSession) {

       webSocketSession.receive().subscribe(inMsg -> {

        if(!inMsg.getPayloadAsText().equals("test-key")) {
            // log.info("AUTHORIZATION ERROR");
            webSocketSession.close();
        }
    });

    List<String> data = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("{A}", "{B}", "{C}"));
    Flux<String> intervalFlux = Flux
                                .interval(Duration.ofMillis(500))
                                .map(tick -> {
                                    if (tick < data.size())
                                        return "item " + tick + ": " + data.get(tick.intValue());
                                    return "Done (tick == data.size())";
                                });

        return webSocketSession.send(intervalFlux
          .map(webSocketSession::textMessage));
    }


}
```

Comment: Could you show a complete code snippet (class and methods)? In which method is that code supposed to be called?

Comment: Hi @BrianClozel, I've started from this code  https://github.com/eugenp/tutorials/tree/master/spring-5-reactive/src/main/java/com/baeldung/reactive/websocket this should be handed inside https://github.com/eugenp/tutorials/blob/master/spring-5-reactive/src/main/java/com/baeldung/reactive/websocket/ReactiveWebSocketHandler.java in the public Mono<Void> handle(WebSocketSession webSocketSession) I've added the snippet above inside this code (I've also did other trials using the declarative way but without result)

Comment: Please edit your question. It’s hard to gather data from several links and figure out what you’ve tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not `subscribe` nor `block` within a reactive pipeline - you can spot you're within such a pipeline because the return type of the handler method is a `Mono<Void>`, meaning a signal that the handling of the incoming messages is done.

In your case, you probably want to read the first message, check that it contains the subscription info you're expecting, and send messages.

```
public class TestWebSocketHandler implements WebSocketHandler {

    public Mono<Void> handle(WebSocketSession session) {

        return session.receive()
                .map(WebSocketMessage::getPayloadAsText)
                .flatMap(msg -> {
                    SubscriptionInfo info = extract(msg);
                    if (info == null) {
                        return session.close();
                    }
                    else {
                        Mono<WebSocketMessage> message = Mono.just(session.textMessage("message"));
                        return session.send(message);
                    }
                })
                .then();
    }

    SubscriptionInfo extract(String message) {
        //
    }

    class SubscriptionInfo {
        //
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Is exactly what I've tried to do! probably the problem is that I was trying working "out" of map and trying to concatenate the send instead of calling it inside the map. Only a theorethical question, the next is required because from a flux I need to have a mono (only one item) in order to apply the function?

Comment: No, it's not required. You could apply it for each message sent in that session. It's probably a mistake and I've changed that in my answer

Comment: In really was correct with the next(), because the flatMax is taking a Function<? super T, ? extends Mono<? extends R> I've responded to my doubt looking at the code! Thanks!